# How to find a directory in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an Intranet web application on a server somewhere, and I wish that application to generate files so I can download them to my local PC.

I connect to this application using a URL in the browser like this...

http://myapp.ourplace.com

and I can get to the software using an ftp connection...

ftp://myapp.ourplace.com

where I can see a directory structure like this...

```
myapp.ourplace.com
    aspnet_client
    bin
    files
    images
    UserControls
    default.aspx
    myapp.bin
    .
    .
    .
```

I need to know how the C# application can locate the directory `files` in the above structure in order to write files into it. I've tried `Environment.CurrentDirectory() + "\\files"` but that doesn't appear to be the same place; no files appear in it at any rate.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Check out this previous answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233735/how-to-get-asp-net-application-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple different ways

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\files\"
```

or

```
Server.MapPath(@"\files\")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found I had to remove the leading backslash character, after which it starting working.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Server.MapPath("files")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't compile. I'm not the only person to have this problem (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518976/server-mappath)), and as the AppDomain method appears to be working I have done that.