# What using directive do I use for Server.MapPath in a separate .cs file in WebMatrix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix, using-directives

I am trying to use `Server.MapPath()` in a separate `.cs` file in WebMatrix.

I can get the method going fine by using `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SomeDirectory/someFile.txt")`

but do I really have to type `HttpContext.Current` every time?

Isn't there any using directive to shorten my typing to simply `Server.MapPath` like it is when coding in a `.cshtml` file?

I have looked here, but none of the answers worked for me. Probably because the answers therein don't target an asp.net-webpages, WebMatrix environment.

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?167802-Server-MapPath-in-C-class

[Server.MapPath()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518976/server-mappath)

Also, if there is a kind of *cheat sheet* to help me find C#.net using directives, considering my environment, letting me know where I can find it is **definitely** an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign the Server property to a variable to save a bit of typing:

```
var server = HttpContext.Current.Server;
var file = server.MapPath("~/SomeDirectory/Somefile");
```

To answer the question posed in the title of your post - the using directive you need in the class file is System.Web:

```
using System.Web;
```

I don't know of any "cheat sheet" as such. Experience and a growing familiarity with MSDN help, as does Resharper if you can afford it and have the full version of Visual Studio.